# mysqli_num_rows from class function error

Tags: php, class, mysqli

This is the first time I learn class in PHP, I tried to make a simple search in database.
here is some script from my class:

```
class DB {
...
function list_query($query) {
    $ns = array();
    $q = mysqli_query($this->con_(), $query);
    while($n = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        $ns[] = $n;
    }
    return $ns;
}
...
function num_query($q) {
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($q);
    return $num;
}
...
}
```

search script :

```
$key = "foo";
$qsearch = $db->list_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE content LIKE '%".$db->escape_query($key)."%'");

$num = $db->num_query($qsearch);
    if ($num == 0) {
        echo "<h2>not found</h2>";
    } else {
        echo "<h2>result for : ".$key."</h2>";

        foreach($qsearch as $val) {
            echo "<h4>".$val['title']."</h2>";
            echo strip_tags($val['content']);
        }
    }
```

but there is an error with the num_query() function.
with warning :

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in class/db.php on line 30.
```

I have checked it with manual mysqli_query() then use the num_query() function, it's work well.

**sorry for my english**

Comment: `$q` is defined in scope of `list_query` function. Assigning `$q` as a global variable or a class property would be useful.

Comment: but I use $q on escape_query($q) function too, but there are work well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `list_query()` returns array. And your `num_query` expects mysqli_result as a parameter.

So, when you write `$qsearch = $db->list_query()`, you're getting an array; and then you pass that array to `num_query`.

Perhaps, your `num_query` should be like:

```
function num_query($result) {
     return count($result);
}
```

Comment: I just realized after using print_r(), if the result is an array. thanks

Comment: Actually i wonder, why do you use object wrapper around `mysqli` interface, if you could simply use PDO that has native methods like `fetchAll()` and `rowCount()`?

Comment: I am still a little knowledge about PDO :)

Comment: Well, it would do you a lot of good, believe me. Writing object wrappers around mysqli is like reinventing a square wheel.